# Cannot add controls to existing DIV element in my ASP page

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, master-pages, code-behind

I'm trying to create a page where links are generated dynamically and added into existing `DIV` element in my `master`page. 
Currently, I'm using `Html.ActionLink()` to display links, but I want to do it dynamically when the page loads.
In my code behind, I cannot reference `menu` item to add links to it. Is there anything I'm missing?

This is the fragment from my master page now.

```
<div id="menu" runat="server">
  <ul>              
      <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Page1","Page1","Home") %></li>
      <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Page2","Page2","Home") %></li>
      <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Page3","Page3","Home") %></li>
  </ul>   
</div>
```

Right now, I'm just trying to come up with a basics so, I'm simply trying to get just one link displayed. Later on, I will want to replace all the `ActionLinks` to be generated from code behind.

This is the part from my master.cs to generate just one link for now:

```
    String str = Url.Action("Page1", "Home");
    HyperLink hp = new HyperLink();
    hp.NavigateUrl = str;
    hp.Text = "Page1";
    menu.Controls.Add(hp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. What I needed to do is just to find my `div` control on the page and add the link control to it:

```
HtmlGenericControl div = this.FindControl("menu") as HtmlGenericControl;
div.Controls.Add(hp);
```